# How to generate array of unique values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to generate an array of unique values but my first number is always 0, how can I fix this?

```
Random r = new Random();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int generatedNumbers = 0;
int winningSum = 0;
int[] list = new int[10];

for (int number = 1; number < list.length; ++number) {
    list[number] = r.nextInt(99);

    for (int uniqueNumber = 0; uniqueNumber < number; ++uniqueNumber) {
        if (list[uniqueNumber] == list[number]) {
            list[number] = r.nextInt(99);
            uniqueNumber = 0;
        }
    }
}
int random_first = r.nextInt(99);)
for (int element : list) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, you have three mistakes (that I noticed).

The first, this loop `for (int number = 1; number < list.length; ++number)` should start with zero. So, `for (int number = 0; number < list.length; ++number)`.

The second, inner check `for (int uniqueNumber = 0; uniqueNumber < number; ++uniqueNumber) {` fails here `uniqueNumber = 0;` It should be `uniqueNumber = -1`.

And finally, you don't need this line `int random_first = r.nextInt(99);)` after outer for loop.

---

Bonus. For easier debugging, you can use a trick. Replace 99 with 10. Why? When you generate a list all values in it should be unique.

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] list = new int[10];

int bound = 10;
for (int number = 0; number < list.length; ++number) {
    list[number] = r.nextInt(bound);

    for (int uniqueNumber = 0; uniqueNumber < number; ++uniqueNumber) {
        if (list[uniqueNumber] == list[number]) {
            list[number] = r.nextInt(bound);
            uniqueNumber = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The body of the if statement may be `--number; break;`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to start from zero, not one, in your for loop

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] list = new int[50];
for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    int newNum = r.nextInt(99);
    outer:while(true){
        for(int i = 0;i<index;i++){
            if(list[i]==newNum){
                newNum = r.nextInt(99);
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    list[index] = newNum;
    
}
for (int element: list) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: It sometimes has non-unique results.

Comment: I fixed it but be careful because it can get stuck if it cannot find another number available so obviously make sure the list is small-ish

Comment: I think `i <list.length` may be `i <index` as OP does.

Comment: that would be more efficient yes